# Emacs Dotted Pair Syntax Improvement

Tags: emacs, elisp

I want to create a dotted pair of variables in Emacs Lisp. But the only way I can find to do it seems really unwieldy. As a simplified example:

```
(let ((width (calculate-width)
      (height (calculate-height))
  `(,width . ,height))
```

This backquote, double-unquote syntax smells to me, but I can't find a neater way and my Google-fu is failing me.

Is there a better way to construct a dotted pair when the values are variables?

*(For clarification, it must be a dotted pair. A straight list won't do.)*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use `cons`:

```
(let ((width (calculate-width))
      (height (calculate-height))
   (cons width height))
```

Comment: I knew I was doing it the hard way, but I didn't know that cons would accept a non-list as the second argument. That's perfect, thanks!

Comment: @KrisJenkins A Cons cell can store anything in both the first and the second component.  Lists are simply special cases of cons cells, i.e. a cons cell, whose second element is another cons cells, whose second element again is another cons cell, and so on.  `'(foo bar baz)` is the very same as `'(foo . (bar . (baz . nil)))`.  This insight is fundamental to understanding the meaning of `cons`, `car`, `cdr` and all the other Lisp list functions.

Comment: Thanks. Clojure was my first Lisp, so I've picked up some expectations from its implementation of cons, where the second argument must be a sequence.